# Can memory leak occur for memory allocated through static variable?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, static, malloc, free

I am given a set of source codes where I have a situation as follows:

Suppose I have one source file (source1.c) which has:

```
static float *var;

void alloc_mem ()
{
  var = (float *) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
}

void some_function (float *data)
{
  // do something with var and data
}
```

In the main function, I have

```
int main()
{
  alloc_mem ();
  some_function (data);
}
```

Now, I cannot free the memory allocated to `var` by calling `free(var)` in main, because it is not in scope there.

Can this situation cause a memory leak? If I define a function in source1.c as

```
void dealloc_mem()
{
  free(var);
}
```

and call it at the end of main, will it work?

Comment: Can a memory leak occur? Yes if you call `alloc_mem()` twice, without an intervening call to `free()` the memory, regardless of how and where the pointer variable is.

Comment: Yes, you can still have memory leaks.  In general, C does not know which pointers are defined or how they got their values, regardless of whether they're `static` or not.  So you need to free the memory yourself (or wait until the program exists, in which case everything is freed (but not by calling `free`)).

Comment: Note that if `alloc_mem()` is called more than once, you definitely have a memory leak.  When called just once, you end up with 'memory in use at exit' or 'still reachable' memory, which is not always regarded as a memory leak.  Adding a deallocator means you can spot other leaks more easily — one less thing to worry about.  Also, you can use [`atexit()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.2) to register `dealloc_mem()` so that it is called as the program exits (and `at_quick_exit()` if you might use `quick_exit()` — added in C11).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, technically speaking it is indeed a memory leak.

Practically speaking, it is often acceptable, since the only time when the memory can be safely deallocated is during program exit, and at this time, it does not really matter if the memory is deallocated or not - it is still going to be returned to OS after program terminates.

To be pedantic, you could `free` the memory in the end of main, but there are more ways to terminate the program than just returning from main, so proper way would be to register exit handler. But it could be an overkill.

I have to mention that from the code provided it is absolutely not clear why dynamic allocation is required in the first place, so I did not address this part.

Comment: *proper way would be to register exit handler* Note that even then there are ways to exit the process without calling any exit handler, such as by calling [`_Exit()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.5)

Comment: @AndrewHenle sure, but there is nothing we can do about it (as well as someone unpowering the rack, for example) so we will just accept this fact of life.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this does cause a memory leak. To convince yourself, you can check that practically with `valgrind`. Put the following in your `source.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static float *var;

void alloc_mem ()
{
    int N = 100;
    var = (float *) malloc(N * sizeof(float));
}

void dealloc_mem()
{
    free(var);
}

void some_function (float *data)
{
  // do something with var and data
}

int main()
{
    float *data;

    alloc_mem ();
    some_function (data);
}
```

Now run `gcc -o executable source.c` and then `valgrind --leak-check=yes ./executable`. It will indicate that you have indeed lost 400 bytes (4 bytes for each of the 100 floats in this example). If you call `dealloc_mem();` as you have suggested at the end of `main`, you won't have any leaks.

Answer (score 2):

> *Can memory leak occur for memory allocated through static variable?*

Yes, of course, if you reassign `var`.

---

> *Now, I cannot free the memory allocated to var by calling `free(var)` in main, because it is not in scope there.*

You can solve that easily by returning `var`.

---

> *If I define a function in `source1.c` as*
>
> ```
> void dealloc_mem()
> {
>     free(var);
> }
> ```
>
> and call it at the end of main, will it work?

Yes, calling `dealloc_mem` appropriately when you no longer need the allocated memory will work fine.

---

The universal rule for memory allocation is that for each `*alloc` there should be a `free`.

Always deallocating memory is a good practice, even at the end of execution, of course when the program ends the memory will be *freed* by the system, but if you run it through a memory checker it will still complain.

---

Aside from that, I don't see a situation where you would need such construct, maybe you can explain why your code is structured like that, otherwise we may be in the presence of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Dynamic allocation because the static allocation is deemed too big?  It would matter if the alternative was a stack allocation — it isn't clear that's the problem here.  At the moment, it's an XY Problem.